# Removing spaces between characters in MD_Parola

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, max7219

I'm using ESP8266 and Max7219 module (8*32) and [MD_Parola library](https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_Parola). To create my own font, at first I used of [MDParolaFontEditor](https://pjrp.github.io/MDParolaFontEditor) and created the following fonts.

[image]

I edited file MD_MAX72xx_font.cpp using Arduino IDE and saved them as 150 and 151. I want to have the output as the following.

[image]

But, the output is as:

[image]

As you can see, there is a space between them! I think this space is automatically added between characters. My problem is that, how can I remove this space?

My code:

```
void loop () {
char MyText[]={151,150,0};
P.displayText(MyText, PA_CENTER, 0, 0, PA_PRINT, PA_NO_EFFECT);
P.displayAnimate(); 
delay(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line in the void setup part

P.setCharSpacing(0);

Answer (score 0):

The matrix with the extra space is 9 (not 8) columns wide (possibly because is was designed to be able to display a colon on a clock).